# Optimize generating a parent bitmask from child bitmasks

Tags: c++, c, optimization, cuda

Given a 64 bit child mask input, for example:

```
10000000 01000000 00100000 00010000 00001000 00000100 00000010 00000000
```

The 8 bit parent mask would be:

```
11111110
```

A single bit in the parent mask maps to 8 bits in the child mask string, and the bit in the parent mask is set to 1 when one of the 8 child bits is set to 1. A simple algorithm to calculate this would be the following:

```
unsigned __int64 childMask = 0x8040201008040200; // The number above in hex
unsigned __int8 parentMask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    const unsigned __int8 child = childMask >> (8 * i);
    parentMask |= (child > 0) << i;
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any optimizations left to do in the code above. The code will be run on CUDA, where I'd like to avoid branches whenever possible. For an answer, code in C++/C will do fine. The for loop can be unrolled, but I'd rather leave that to the compiler to optimize, giving hints where necessary using for example the `#pragma unroll`.

Comment: Merge 32 bit halves then 16 then 8.  Or you can use vector extensions comparison to 0 vector if your compiler and architecture supports it.

Comment: cuda has [warp vote instrinsics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) (e.g. `__ballot_sync()`) which can do this operation in a single instruction, when your child bitmasks are distributed one per thread in the warp.

Comment: @RobertCrovella for this algorithm every thread has to process multiple unique 64 bit child masks. I could maybe process them by running the ballot_sync 8 times, one for every child mask for every thread. I find it hard to visualize whether this would be faster or not, but I will run a performance comparison if I can get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach is to use `__vcmpgtu4` to do the per-byte comparisons, which returns the result as packed masks, which can be AND-ed with 0x08040201 (0x80402010 for the high half) to turn them into the bits of the final result, but then they need to be summed horizontally which does not seem to be well-supported but it can be done with plain old C-style code.

For example,

```
unsigned int low = childMask;
unsigned int high = childMask >> 32;
unsigned int lowmask = __vcmpgtu4(low, 0) & 0x08040201;
unsigned int highmask = __vcmpgtu4(high, 0) & 0x80402010;
unsigned int mask = lowmask | highmask;
mask |= mask >> 16;
mask |= mask >> 8;
parentMask = mask & 0xff;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion! According to my benchmarks this saves about 20% compared to the default algorithm.

Comment: @RobbinMarcus by the way you've probably noticed this, but if the input mask is already in that 0x08040201 form (which you showed in the example) then the whole `__vcmpgtu4` thing can be skipped

Answer (score 1):

This solution based on classical bit-twiddling techniques may be faster than the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155652/780717) on at least some GPU architectures supported by CUDA, since `__vcmp*` intrinsics are not fast on all of them.

Since GPUs are basically 32-bit architectures, the 64-bit `childMask` is processed as two halves, `hi` and `lo`.

The processing consists of three steps. In the first step, we set each non-null byte to `0x80` and leave the byte unmodified otherwise. In other words, we set the most significant bit of each byte if the byte is non-zero. One method is to use a modified version of a null-byte detection algorithm Alan Mycroft devised in the 1980s and which is often used for `C`-string processing. Alternatively we can use the fact that `hadd (~0, x)` has the most significant bit set only if `x != 0`, where `hadd` is a halving add: `hadd (a, b) = (a + b) / 2`, *without* overflow in the intermediate computation. An efficient implementation was published by Peter L. Montgomery in 2000.

In the second step, we collect the most significant bits of each byte into the highest nibble. For this, we need to move bit 7 to bit 28, bits 15 to bit 29, bit 23 to bit 30, and bit 31 to bits 31, corresponding to the shift factors of 21, 14, 7, and 0. In order to avoid separate shifts, we combine the shift factors into a single "magic" multiplier, then multiply with that, thus performing all shifts in parallel.

In the third step we combine the nibbles containing the result and move them into the correct bit position. For the `hi` word, that means moving the nibble in bits <31:28> into bits <7:4> and for the `lo` word this means moving the nibble in bits <31:28> into bits <3:0>. This combination can be performed either with bit-wise OR or addition. Which variant is faster may depend on the target architecture.

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define USE_HAROLDS_SOLUTION  (0)

#define USE_MYCROFT_ZEROBYTE  (0)
#define USE_TWO_MASKS         (1)
#define USE_ADD_COMBINATION   (1)

uint8_t parentMask (uint64_t childMask)
{
#if USE_TWO_MASKS
    const uint32_t LSB_MASK = 0x01010101;
#endif // USE_TWO_MASKS
    const uint32_t MSB_MASK = 0x80808080;
    const uint32_t MAGICMUL = (1 << 21) | (1 << 14) | (1 << 7) | (1 << 0);
    uint32_t lo, hi;

    /* split 64-bit argument into two halves for 32-bit GPU architecture */
    lo = (uint32_t)(childMask >>  0);
    hi = (uint32_t)(childMask >> 32);

#if USE_MYCROFT_ZEROBYTE
    /* Set most significant bit in each byte that is not zero. Adapted from Alan 
       Mycroft's null-byte detection algorithm (newsgroup comp.lang.c, 1987/04/08,
       https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/2HtQXvg7iKc/xOJeipH6KLMJ):
       null_byte(x) = ((x - 0x01010101) & (~x & 0x80808080))
    */
#if USE_TWO_MASKS
    lo = (((lo | MSB_MASK) - LSB_MASK) | lo) & MSB_MASK;
    hi = (((hi | MSB_MASK) - LSB_MASK) | hi) & MSB_MASK;
#else // USE_TWO_MASKS
    lo = (((lo & ~MSB_MASK) + ~MSB_MASK) | lo) & MSB_MASK;
    hi = (((hi & ~MSB_MASK) + ~MSB_MASK) | hi) & MSB_MASK;
#endif // USE_TWO_MASKS

#else // USE_MYCROFT_ZEROBYTE

    /* Set most significant bit in each byte that is not zero. Use hadd(~0,x).
       Peter L. Montgomery's observation (newsgroup comp.arch, 2000/02/11,
       https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.arch/gXFuGZtZKag/_5yrz2zDbe4J):
       (A+B)/2 = (A AND B) + (A XOR B)/2.
    */
#if USE_TWO_MASKS
    lo = (((~lo & ~LSB_MASK) >> 1) + lo) & MSB_MASK;
    hi = (((~hi & ~LSB_MASK) >> 1) + hi) & MSB_MASK;
#else // USE_TWO_MASKS
    lo = (((~lo >> 1) & ~MSB_MASK) + lo) & MSB_MASK;
    hi = (((~hi >> 1) & ~MSB_MASK) + hi) & MSB_MASK;
#endif // USE_TWO_MASKS

#endif // USE_MYCROFT_ZEROBYTE

    /* collect most significant bit of each byte in most significant nibble */
    lo = lo * MAGICMUL;
    hi = hi * MAGICMUL;

    /* combine nibbles with results for high and low half into final result */
#if USE_ADD_COMBINATION    
    return (uint8_t)((hi >> 24) + (lo >> 28));
#else // USE_ADD_COMBINATION
    return (uint8_t)((hi >> 24) | (lo >> 28));
#endif // USE_ADD_COMBINATION
}

uint8_t parentMask_ref (uint64_t childMask)
{
    uint8_t parentMask = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        uint8_t child = childMask >> (8 * i);
        parentMask |= (child > 0) << i;
    }
    return parentMask;
}

uint32_t build_mask (uint32_t a)
{
    return ((a & 0x80808080) >> 7) * 0xff;
}

uint32_t vcmpgtu4 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint32_t r;
    r = ((a & ~b) + (((a ^ ~b) >> 1) & 0x7f7f7f7f));
    r = build_mask (r);
    return r;
}

uint8_t parentMask_harold (uint64_t childMask)
{
    uint32_t low = childMask;
    uint32_t high = childMask >> 32;
    uint32_t lowmask = vcmpgtu4 (low, 0) & 0x08040201;
    uint32_t highmask = vcmpgtu4 (high, 0) & 0x80402010;
    uint32_t mask = lowmask | highmask;
    mask |= mask >> 16;
    mask |= mask >> 8;
    return (uint8_t)mask;
}

/*
  From: geo <gmars...@gmail.com>
  Newsgroups: sci.math,comp.lang.c,comp.lang.fortran
  Subject: 64-bit KISS RNGs
  Date: Sat, 28 Feb 2009 04:30:48 -0800 (PST)

  This 64-bit KISS RNG has three components, each nearly
  good enough to serve alone.    The components are:
  Multiply-With-Carry (MWC), period (2^121+2^63-1)
  Xorshift (XSH), period 2^64-1
  Congruential (CNG), period 2^64
*/
static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;
#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

int main (void)
{
    uint64_t childMask, count = 0;
    uint8_t res, ref;

    do {
        childMask = KISS64;
        ref = parentMask_ref (childMask);
#if USE_HAROLDS_SOLUTION
        res = parentMask_harold (childMask);
#else // USE_HAROLDS_SOLUTION
        res = parentMask (childMask);
#endif // USE_HAROLDS_SOLUTION
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("\narg=%016llx  res=%02x  ref=%02x\n", childMask, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (!(count & 0xffffff)) printf ("\r%llu", count);
        count++;
    } while (1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```